# More efficient way to bruteforce finding solutions to (x+y)^2=str(x)+str(y)? Can it be vectorised?

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, comparison, string-comparison

So far I have written:

```
n=1000
solutions=[]
for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in range(1,n+1):
        if str((i+j)**2)==str(i)+str(j):
            solutions.append("("+str(i)+"+"+str(j)+")^2 = "+str((i+j)**2))
for solution in solutions:
    print(solution)
```

This takes 1.03 seconds on my computer. Is there a quicker way to implement the comparison? I found a page on [vectorisation](https://realpython.com/numpy-array-programming/#what-is-vectorization) but I'm not sure how I would generate the list I would need to then vectorise the comparison.

Comment: list objects *don't support vectorization*

Comment: Sorry, by "generate the list" I should have said "generate the array" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished even faster by searching for an `(x, y)` pair that satisfies the equation for a given square in your target range. In fact, this reduces the problem from `O(n^2)` to `O(nlogn)` time complexity.

```
def split_root(n):
    div = 10
    while div < n:
        x, y = divmod(n, div)
        div *= 10
        if not y or y < div // 100: continue
        if (x + y) ** 2 == n: yield x, y
```

Then just iterate over the possible squares:

```
def squares(n):
    for i in range(n):
        for sr in split_root(i ** 2):
            yield "({}+{})^2 = {}".format(*sr, sum(sr)**2)
```

Example usage:

```
print("\n".join(squares(100000)))
```

Output:

```
(8+1)^2 = 81
(20+25)^2 = 2025
(30+25)^2 = 3025
(88+209)^2 = 88209
(494+209)^2 = 494209
(494+1729)^2 = 4941729
(744+1984)^2 = 7441984
(2450+2500)^2 = 24502500
(2550+2500)^2 = 25502500
(5288+1984)^2 = 52881984
(6048+1729)^2 = 60481729
(3008+14336)^2 = 300814336
(4938+17284)^2 = 493817284
(60494+17284)^2 = 6049417284
(68320+14336)^2 = 6832014336
```

For comparison, your original solution-

```
def op_solver(n):
    solutions = []
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        for j in range(1,n+1):
            if str((i+j)**2)==str(i)+str(j):
                solutions.append("("+str(i)+"+"+str(j)+")^2 = "+str((i+j)**2))
    return solutions


>>> timeit("op_solver(1000)", setup="from __main__ import op_solver", number=5) / 5
0.8715057126013562
```

My solution-

```
>>> timeit("list(squares(2000))", setup="from __main__ import squares", number=100) / 100
0.006898956680088304
```

Roughly a 125x speedup for your example usage range, and it will run asymptotically faster as `n` grows.

This also has the benefit of being faster and simpler than the numpy solution, without of course requiring numpy. If you do need a faster version, I'm sure you can even vectorize my code to get the best of both worlds.

Comment: Wow that's crazy fast. I managed to run up to n=10M and it only took 90s. I also ran into memory issues with unutbu's method, using n=20k resulted in running out of available memory and the script crashing. Yours has barely any memory use! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can make the calculation faster by avoiding string manipulation.
Instead of concatenating strings, use `i * 10**(int(math.log10(j))+1) + j` to "concatenate" numerically:

```
In [457]: i, j = 20, 25; i * 10**(int(math.log10(j))+1) + j
Out[457]: 2025
```

You can also use NumPy to vectorize the calculation:

```
import numpy as np
n = 1000

def using_numpy(n):
    i = range(1, n+1)
    j = range(1, n+1)
    I, J = np.meshgrid(i, j)

    left = (I+J)**2
    j_digits = np.log10(J).astype(int) + 1
    right = I*10**j_digits + J
    mask = left == right
    solutions = ['({i}+{j})^2 = {k}'.format(i=i, j=j, k=k)
                 for i, j, k in zip(I[mask], J[mask], left[mask])]
    return solutions

def using_str(n):
    solutions=[]
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        for j in range(1,n+1):
            if str((i+j)**2)==str(i)+str(j):
                solutions.append("("+str(i)+"+"+str(j)+")^2 = "+str((i+j)**2))
    return solutions

print('\n'.join(using_numpy(n)))
# print('\n'.join(using_str(n)))
```

yields

```
(8+1)^2 = 81
(20+25)^2 = 2025
(30+25)^2 = 3025
(88+209)^2 = 88209
(494+209)^2 = 494209
```

---

For `n = 1000`, `using_numpy` is about 16x faster than `using_str`:

```
In [455]: %timeit using_str(n)
500 ms ± 251 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [470]: %timeit using_numpy(n)
31.1 ms ± 98.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for. Looks like I've got a lot to read up on about masks and zip. Thanks also for the different way to get values substituted into a string, that's much neater. I also really like your way of printing out the solutions, looks nicer than iterating through the list and printing each element.